# Machine Learning algorithm for finding drug based on diagnosis

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction

Training Data Set:

```
--------------------   
Patient Age:        25
Patient Weight:     60
Diagnosis one:      Fever
Diagnosis two:      Headache

    > Medicine:           **Crocin**

---------------------------------
Patient Age:        25
Patient Weight:     60
Diagnosis one:      Fever
Diagnosis two:      no headache

    > Medicine:           Paracetamol

----------------------------------
```

Give sample data set with drug/medicne prescribed to patient.

How to find what medicine based on patient info(age/weight) and diagnosis(fever/headeache/etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you are aiming at is **classification** since the target values are a nominal scale.

Getting the vocabulary right is crucial since all the rest of the work is already done by others such as in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) library for Python which contains most relevant algorithms and plenty of data to test them and learn the algorithms.

It seems you have four variables as input:

1. age - metric variable
2. weight - metric variable
3. Diagnosis one - nominal variable
4. Diagnosis two - nominal variable

You will have to encode you nominal variables, where I would recommend an array of all possible diagnosis such as:

Fever, Headache, Stomach pain, x - [0, 0, 0, 0]

Now each array element will be set to 1 if the diagnosis is correct and 0 else. 
Therefore you have a total of 2 + n input variables, whereas n is the number of possible symptoms.

Then you can simply go to the sklearn library and start using the most simple classification algorithm: [Nearest Neighbour Classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors-classification)

If this does not yield good result (probably results will be not good), you can start to use more sophisticated models (SVM, RandomForest). Yet first you should learn the vocabulary and use simple models to get to know the methods and the processing chain.